# Poor Julia performance from R

Tags: r, julia, benchmarking

I've been studying the idea of using Julia as a replacement for C++ as a secondary language to speed up R scripts. Therefore, I'm writing a short script to compare the performance of the three languages, using an R script as the main file reproduced below:

```r
# Loading packages
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)
library(JuliaConnectoR)
library(microbenchmark)

# Generating data
set.seed(9392927)
N <- 1e3L
x1 <- matrix(rpois(N ^ 2L, lambda = 10L), N)
x2 <- matrix(rpois(N ^ 2L, lambda = 10L), N)

# Defining functions
mySolveR <- function(m) {
  return(solve(m))
}
myProdR <- function(m1, m2) {
  return(m1 %*% m2)
}
cppFunction("
  arma::mat mySolveCpp(arma::mat m) {
    return(inv(m));
  }",
  depends = "RcppArmadillo"
)
cppFunction("
  arma::mat myProdCpp(arma::mat m1, arma::mat m2) {
    return(m1 * m2);
  }",
  depends = "RcppArmadillo"
)
mySolveJulia <- juliaEval("
  function mySolveJulia(m)
    return(inv(m))
  end"
)
#> Starting Julia ...
myProdJulia <- juliaEval("
  function myProdJulia(m1, m2)
    return(m1 * m2)
  end"
)

# Benchmarking
reps <- 10L
print(
  microbenchmark(
      mySolveR(x1), mySolveCpp(x1), mySolveJulia(x1),
      times = reps
    )
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>              expr        min         lq      mean     median        uq
#>      mySolveR(x1)   41.53371   44.03872  186.4527   59.43063  465.0983
#>    mySolveCpp(x1)   49.42867   72.63049  240.0839   81.16933  440.1176
#>  mySolveJulia(x1) 3856.43147 3897.36013 5112.4448 5376.94133 6026.1369
#>        max neval cld
#>   528.8838    10  a 
#>   576.2336    10  a 
#>  6220.1093    10   b
print(
  microbenchmark(
    myProdR(x1, x2), myProdCpp(x1, x2), myProdJulia(x1, x2),
    times = reps
  )
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                 expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq
#>      myProdR(x1, x2)   20.10827   23.50031   27.69398   25.18961   32.51614
#>    myProdCpp(x1, x2)   25.59671   29.59619   38.32624   31.83016   49.33401
#>  myProdJulia(x1, x2) 5698.10212 6135.62034 6353.71632 6412.39110 6487.12516
#>         max neval cld
#>    39.89406    10  a 
#>    57.82850    10  a 
#>  7243.81362    10   b
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

At this stage, I am not worried about which language performs best, I even suppose such simple functions would perform at the same order of magnitude, but I am surprised that Julia is performing so poorly.

My only guesses have to do with unnecessary recompilation of code or of Julia instance launches, but using `startJuliaServer()`/`stopJulia()` doesn't help, and neither does isolating the functions in their own source files. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you should add a link to the github issue where the author of `JuliaConnectoR` answered (unless you want to put this as an answer here): https://github.com/stefan-m-lenz/JuliaConnectoR/issues/21

Comment: @bretauv will do both, thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 4):

I have not used JuliaConnectoR, but I tested JuliaCall:

Setup (maybe things can be written in a cleaner way - I just checked [JuliaCall manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/JuliaCall/readme/README.html); you can check sources of example packages [listed here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/JuliaCall/readme/README.html#juliacall-for-r-package-developers) to see more carefully designed code):

```
library(JuliaCall)
library(microbenchmark)
julia <- julia_setup()
set.seed(9392927)
N <- 1e3L
x1 <- matrix(rpois(N ^ 2L, lambda = 10L), N)
x2 <- matrix(rpois(N ^ 2L, lambda = 10L), N)
mySolveR <- function(m) {
  return(solve(m))
}
myProdR <- function(m1, m2) {
  return(m1 %*% m2)
}
julia_eval("
function mySolveJulia(m)
      return(inv(m))
end")
mySolveJulia <- function(m) {
    julia_call("mySolveJulia", m)
}

julia_eval("
function myProdJulia(m1, m2)
    return(m1 * m2)
end")
myProdJulia <- function(m1, m2) {
    julia_call("myProdJulia", m1, m2)
}
```

And benchmark:

```
> reps <- 10L
> print(
+   microbenchmark(
+       mySolveR(x1), mySolveJulia(x1),
+       times = reps
+     )
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
             expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
     mySolveR(x1) 516.1157 517.4391 520.98363 520.60125 522.0257 531.6278    10
 mySolveJulia(x1)  50.8057  52.9256  73.29882  55.88265  67.5247 167.2614    10
> print(
+   microbenchmark(
+     myProdR(x1, x2), myProdJulia(x1, x2),
+     times = reps
+   )
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
                expr      min       lq    mean   median       uq      max neval
     myProdR(x1, x2) 499.3371 509.4347 526.256 523.8693 532.5146 562.5851    10
 myProdJulia(x1, x2) 331.7332 332.5554 354.807 337.0199 351.8239 492.5586    10
```

Surprisingly, I have significantly higher timings for R than you (but maybe this is a difference in machines on which the test is run).

Also if you want to see how much time is spent in data transport here are benchmarks in Julia:

```
julia> using Distributions

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> x1 = rand(Poisson(10), 1000, 1000);

julia> x2 = rand(Poisson(10), 1000, 1000);

julia> @benchmark inv($x1)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 168 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  25.273 ms … 55.200 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 9.74%
 Time  (median):     28.539 ms              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   29.815 ms ±  4.172 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  2.40% ± 3.90%

     ▃█▂▃▁▂ ▄▆▁▄  ▂
  ▃▁███████▇████▇▄█▅▅█▃▃▁▁▅▄▄▁▁▁▄▃▄▅▃▁▃▁▁▃▃▇▁▁▁▃▁▃▁▄▁▁▁▁▃▁▃▁▃ ▃
  25.3 ms         Histogram: frequency by time        42.1 ms <

 Memory estimate: 15.76 MiB, allocs estimate: 7.

julia> @benchmark $x1 * $x2
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 17 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  293.104 ms … 321.683 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     309.639 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   309.618 ms ±   8.177 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.11% ± 0.31%

  ▁            ▁   ▁  ▁▁     ▁    ▁ ▁█ ▁    ▁        ▁ ▁   ▁▁ ▁
  █▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁█▁▁██▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁█▁██▁█▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█▁█▁▁▁██▁█ ▁
  293 ms           Histogram: frequency by time          322 ms <

 Memory estimate: 7.66 MiB, allocs estimate: 5.
```

Answer (score 2):

With your code you restart Julia at each call. Below is how I would do. But I don't get a better timing with Julia, contrary to @BogumilKaminksi. I don't know why.

```r
library(JuliaConnectoR)

juliaModule <- "
module myJuliaModule
export mySolveJulia
export myProdJulia

function mySolveJulia(m)
  return inv(m)
end

function myProdJulia(m1, m2)
  return m1 * m2
end

end
"

. <- juliaEval(juliaModule)
myJuliaModule <- juliaImport(".myJuliaModule", all = FALSE)
mySolveJulia <- myJuliaModule$mySolveJulia

mySolveR <- function(x) solve(x)
set.seed(9392927)
N <- 1e3L
x1 <- matrix(rpois(N ^ 2L, lambda = 10L), N)
x2 <- matrix(rpois(N ^ 2L, lambda = 10L), N)

reps <- 10L
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  mySolveR(x1), 
  mySolveJulia(x1),
  times = reps
)

stopJulia()
```

Comment: The reason is that JuliaConnectoR seems to use a more expensive way than JuliaCall to transport data. That is why in my answer I have shown "pure Julia" timings, as the rest is data interchange overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Following a suggestion, I'm adding a link to the conversation I had with one of the authors of JuliaConnectoR on GitHub: https://github.com/stefan-m-lenz/JuliaConnectoR/issues/21

The gist of his reply is:

> For communicating with Julia, the JuliaConnectoR uses TCP. This requires IO operations which will add to the execution time. [...] The IO operations is simply much slower than the execution of these highly optimized functions on memory. [...] With the JuliaConnectoR, you have some more communication overhead for the IO via TCP. So you can't use it to measure the Julia performance itself via measuring the execution time of the whole operation in R.

So my practical solution was to implement my more-realistic-function example (where I got Julia and C++ to outperform R, as expected) and use the simpler functions from the OP as a counterexample (i.e., when it's not worth translating the R code).